# How to implement a trait on any type that implements PgExecutor?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, rust-sqlx

I have my own trait to extend the functionality that the `PgExecutor` trait provides.

I want to implement these trait on anything that implements `PgExecutor` but I'm honestly having a hard time.

```rust
#[async_trait]
impl<'a, T> PgExecutorExt for T
    where T: PgExecutor<'a> + Sync
 {
    async fn my_read_method(&self) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        sqlx::query_as!(...)
        .fetch_one(self)
        .await?;

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
the trait bound `&T: Executor<'_>` is not satisfied
the trait `Executor<'_>` is not implemented for `&T`
```

On the `.fetch_one(self)` call

anyone has any clue on what is going on??
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Executor::fetch_one()`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.Executor.html#method.fetch_one) function takes `self`, not `&self`.  You need to change `&self` to `self` in your trait definition and this implementation, and that should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you! It basically worked by doing `*self`